# Problem displaying degrees celsius with siunitx and xelatex

Tags: xetex, siunitx

I'm trying to discuss a temperature in a document where   I'm using xelatex and siunitx.

```
       The temperature was further increased to \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}.
```

When using xelatex this causes a hollow box to appear in place of the unit. When using pdflatex and a distribution supplied font it works fine. Is there a solution to this that I have missed?

This is a link to a character guide for the font -- ITC Baskerville Std Roman -- I'm using.
http://store2.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-UK&event=displayFont&code=BASQ10005000

I've also tried Times New Roman with no joy.

I'm using a fully updated texlive 2011.

Many thanks,

MWE

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{fontspec}                              
 \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
 %\usepackage{xkeyval}
 %\usepackage{polyglossia}                          
 %\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}             
 %\usepackage{etoolbox} 
 \usepackage{siunitx}

 \begin{document}
 The temperature was \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}.
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, now edited.

Comment: Thanks for posting some example code. I've made it "more minimal" by commenting out all unneeded `\usepackage` commands, setting the document class to "article," and by shortening the sentence. In addition, I've added an image file to show the resulting output.

Comment: Thanks  Mico. How do you add an image of the output?

Comment: @JosephWright: If this MWE is run under `lualatex` instead of `xelatex`, no hollow rectangle is displayed, but also no raised little circle followed by "C" either. (I.e., nothing at all shows.) :-(

Comment: To start loading an image, click on the blue rectangle above the editing box and follow the directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on Joseph's answer, you can find a matching font that has the required symbol; for instance, if your Times New Roman hasn't the ℃ symbol, then you can do

```
\newfontfamily{\tgtermes}[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{℃}{{\tgtermes ℃}}
\sisetup{text-celsius = ℃}
```

thereby using the different font only for the character you need. Alternatively, you can also try faking the symbol:

```
\sisetup{text-celsius = $^\circ\mkern-1mu$C}
```

(adjust the amount of kerning).

Comment: Is there a simple way to adjust the kerning when doing it like this? \sisetup{text-celsius = °C}  I tried your second suggestion but it wouldn't  typeset.

Comment: @Darling Sorry for the typo!

Comment: @egreg wouldn't it be safer to use \ensuremath{} instead of dollar signs here? Is there any particular reason to choose the dollar signs over \ensuremath{}?

Comment: @MS It's `text-celsius`, isn't it?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this definition of celsius will never be used in math mode and thus it is ensured that the dollar signs will always toggle math mode in the correct way? and thanks for the reply on this ages-old post.

Comment: @MS Well, this is no longer important, because `text-celsius` no longer exists!

Comment: @MS The latest version doesn't need it and, besides U+2103 decomposes as U+00B0 U+0043

Comment: @egreg I see, this answer was helpful for me nevertheless as it enabled me to redeclare '\degreeCelsius' for a font that was apparently missing the U+00B0 character using your method. And since that might be used in math mode, I used \ensuremath{} and was wondering why you didn't. Now I know :)

Answer (score 5):

The `siunitx` package has a set of basic symbol choices built in for working with standard LaTeX fonts. However, these may or may not work when loading system fonts with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Fonts do not cover all symbols, and it is simply not realistic to detect every possible combination. Thus when using non-standard fonts it is down to the end user to make an appropriate choice, using for example

```
\sisetup{text-celsius = <symbol or appropriate macro>}
```

The log file may show

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

if the appropriate symbols are not available. (This will depend on the font in use.)

Answer (score 3):

use the TeX Gyre Times font, is has a degree symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{fontspec}      
\fontspec[Extension=.otf,
          BoldFont=texgyretermes-bold,
          ItalicFont=texgyretermes-italic,
          BoldItalicFont=texgyretermes-bolditalic]{texgyretermes-regular}
\addfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
 The temperature was \SI{200}{\degreeCelsius}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using Linux, then pay attention, that `xelatex` finds the open type fonts of TeXLive, located at `$texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/texgyre/`. With `lualatex` it is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting another, updated answer as I just had a very similar issue with LuaLaTeX and the siunitx package has changed since this question was posted and the answer is now outdated as

```
\sisetup{text-celsius = <symbol or appropriate macro>}
```

no longer works. Putting this code in my preamble fixed a missing degree symbol for me:

```
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = \,]{\degreeCelsius}{\ensuremath{\degree} C}
```